# How to transfer zip file to aws ec2 from local machine?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have written APIs in php, and I want to upload the API to an Amazon EC2 instance.

- How can I upload it in the form of zip file?
- How can I extract the zip on the EC2 instance?
- How to access them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> First is how to upload in the form of zip file,

You can use `scp` command to transfer files from local machine to your EC2 server

```
scp -i your.pem yourzip ec2-user@yourEC2IP:/tmp
```

> and then how i can extract zip at ec2.

You can use unzip command on your ec2 instance

```
unzip yourzip
```

> Finally how to access them

Your API package must be deployed in a web container. Once your web application is deployed and your web container is running, make sure the port is opened for your access form the Security Groups. This is a brief answer because providing all the steps is no practical, maybe do a bit of reading and research.

Comment: Can we unzip immediately after scp copied the zip file to ec2? automatically after scp command is run? I have a shell script which makes the build, make zip and then upload to ec2 using scp command. Now I had to manually unzip the files. Any idea how can I unzip it directly in server from same shell script?